# Average score for a given name within the current month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table data set of customer service reps score per call for the current year and I'm trying to build a query to calculate the average score for a given name within a given month

Something like calculating the average score for Matt's calls for the month of January.

I've been trying but I'm a begginer at SQL so I'm having trouble.

So far I've got this:

```
Select avg("general score") as General_Score, avg("Re_score") as Re_score 
from Voc2019 
Where [Name] ="Matt"
```

This gives me a error type mismatch

Would greatly appreciate any help you can provide to me.

UPDATE:

the code now works but While this does work I still need to order by a given date, but I I want to use this sql string to retrieve the average for a month specified varying on the month I want from excel but it's not returning any results

For instance I want Avg score for Matt in January

Currently I got

```
Select avg([general score]) as general_score, ("Re_score") as Re_score 
from Voc2019 
Where [Name] ="Matt" and Score_Date = Month(2)
```

Comment: Your update to your question seems to disregard the advice already provided by the answers given. Also, the `Month` function requires a date argument, for which it will return the month number.

Comment: I'm sorry that was not my intention I did take into consideration and I am using it the way you described in access but is there there any way using a mid  function or something since it's text based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you are using a string (`"general score"`) when attempting to reference a field (this is likely producing the type mismatch error).

You haven't indicated the field in your table that contains the date for each record, and so selecting the appropriate set of records for a given month is impossible without this information.

However, to correct your current code, I would suggest the following:

```
select avg(voc2019.[general score]) as General_Score, avg(voc2019.re_score) as Re_score 
from voc2019 
where voc2019.name = "Matt"
```

If you were to identify the field containing the date for each record, you could calculate an average per month using something like:

```
select 
    dateserial(year(voc2019.date), month(voc2019.date), 1) as [Month],
    avg(voc2019.[general score]) as General_Score, 
    avg(voc2019.re_score) as Re_score 
from 
    voc2019 
where 
    voc2019.name = "Matt"
group by
    dateserial(year(voc2019.date), month(voc2019.date), 1)
```

The above assumes that your table `voc2019` contains a field called `date` dating each record.

#### EDIT:

Since your date is actually stored as a Text field rather than a Date field, you can use the `DateValue` function to parse the text content into a date value.

Hence, to obtain the average score for Matt in January, you might use something like the following:

```
select 
    avg(voc2019.[general score]) as General_Score, 
    avg(voc2019.re_score) as Re_score 
from 
    voc2019 
where 
    voc2019.name = "Matt" and 
    month(datevalue(voc2019.date)) = 1 and
    year(datevalue(voc2019.date)) = 2019
```

Alternatively, since your date is stored as text, you could use the `like` operator to match only dates in January, e.g.:

```
select 
    avg(voc2019.[general score]) as General_Score, 
    avg(voc2019.re_score) as Re_score 
from 
    voc2019 
where 
    voc2019.name = "Matt" and voc2019.date like "##-01-2019"
```

Comment: Yes I did left out the where part because I had no idea how to reference date I do have a date field in string format as dd-mm-yyyy since I'm off work right and have no way to reach the file I will try this asap and get back to you. But your explanation was amazing it will definitely help a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @Aeon Where you state *"I have a date field in string format"* Is the data type of your field **Date/Time** or **Text**?

Comment: It's text I'm going to check your solution now

Comment: Both answers are correct my selected answer is valid for specific access sql @JasonInVegas answer is correct for regular sql I used both answers for different purposes is there any way to credit both? Finally thanks a lot to both of you I learned a lot from this especially the difference from quote and double quote

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I am way more familiar with Oracle SQL syntax, but pretty sure the problem is with some [simple MS Access syntax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-sql-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-444d0303-cde1-424e-9a74-e8dc3e460671). Your literal string "Matt" which should be single-quoted as in 'Matt' and the square brackets are used to enclose a column identifier only when it contains a space.

Try:

```
Select avg([general score]) as General_Score, avg(Re_score) as Re_score 
from Voc2019 
Where Name = 'Matt'
```

Comment: Updated my question